# RSACryptoServiceProvider in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, x509certificate2

I'm developing a .NET 6 application, which should use an old library in .NET Framework. Because it was too old to even open in VS2022 I did an upgrade to .NET 6.

The problem is some things don't seem to work and need a rewrite because of incompatibility between .NET 6 and .NET Framework.

1. Case one

One of those things seems to be RSACryptoServiceProvider or this whole part

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)this.cert.PrivateKey;
CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters();
cspParameters.KeyContainerName = rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
cspParameters.KeyNumber = rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2;

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaAesCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
byte[] signature = rsaAesCSP.SignData(bytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

When using this library I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider

The certificate class is X509Certificate2.

How can I replace this part of the code so it would be compatible with .NET 6?

I tried with this:

```
            var rsa = this.cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(bytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

2. Case 2

```
            SignedXml xmlSig = new SignedXml(msg);

            byte[] pubKey = this.cert.GetPublicKey();
            string pubKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pubKey);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)this.cert.PrivateKey;
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
            cspParams.KeyNumber = rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaAesCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            xmlSig.SigningKey = rsaAesCSP;
```

here it's a similar problem. I can replace it here also with:

```
var rsa = this.cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
xmlSig.SigningKey = rsa;
```

but I'm not sure this is the correct way, because by "fixing" both of this in this way I got a new error in another file. Do you think this would be correct?

P.S. just that you know what I'm talking about. I'm using and upgrading this library: https://github.com/zvizdo/MadWare.Furs

By updating the stuff listed above what breaks next is this:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090330): The specified data could not be decrypted.
```

More exactly this line:

```
                HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync(url, cnt).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

in this file: https://github.com/zvizdo/MadWare.Furs/blob/master/src/MadWare.Furs/Http/SoapHttpService.cs

Keep in mind I replaced also

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
```

with

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
```

to have this compile.

EDIT 2:
I have set the HttpClientHandler to Tls 1.2 manually and now I got a different error which says that the certificate is expired. Now at least I know what is wrong in the end. I will update the post accordingly, when I get a valid one and try again.

Comment: Which line in the code gives you the error? what is the type of `this.cert.PrivateKey` ?

Comment: The error is on the first line. PrivateKey is of type AsymmetricAlgorithm

Comment: You don't need to run the "CSP upgrade" on RSA instances that aren't RSACryptoServiceProvider.  Both substitutions using GetRSAPrivateKey looks correct... any problems you're still having would require details as to what breaks later.

Comment: @bartonjs I updated the original post again with more info

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 4.7 (and all versions of .NET Core) you must not access `PrivateKey` property on `X509Certificate2` object. It is obsolete and will fail on newer frameworks. Here is the blog post I wrote on this subject: https://www.pkisolutions.com/accessing-and-using-certificate-private-keys-in-net-framework-net-core/. Instead, you have to use an appropriate [X509Certificate2 extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-6.0#extension-methods) to access the private key. There is an extension method for every public key algorithm type (RSA, DSA or ECDSA) and then access relevant properties to retrieve required information.

Comment: I have already read this article actually. But I'm still not sure how to get out CspKeyContainerInfo data from RSA. Because if I use  `var rsa = this.cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();` then rsa doesn't support this extension methods. Can you help with clarifying this?

Comment: what exactly you need from `CspKeyContainerInfo`? Based on your code, you don't need this information. It would be useful if you tell the objective of your task. If you need to sign data, then use `RSA.SignData()` appropriate method.

Comment: In this case I have to SignData, but the SignData method takes at least 3 arguemnts. Is it correct to set it like this: `            byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(bytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
` ? I don't know what padding setting is correct.

Comment: In another case I have to set the SignedXml.SigningKey. In this case I can set this rsa object as the signing key, but I'm not sure this is the correct.

Comment: I added more information in the original post