# What is the updated version of SetPinForPrivateKey in .NET 6

Tags: c#

I need to set pin for smartcard. I was using the extension method below in .NET Framework 4.8. Then I decided to update my application using .NET 6 and I'm stuck. The problem is that the line:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

In .NET 6 the return type of certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng and the method is obsolote. I found there is certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey() method in .NET 6
but the return type is RSA.

Is there any updated code for .NET 6 or can I convert RSACng to RSACryptoServiceProvider?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace X509CertExtension
{
    internal static class X509Certificate2Extension
    {
        public static bool SetPinForPrivateKey(this X509Certificate2 certificate, string pin)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                // Here I've got the error in .NET 6
                // System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.'
                RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

                IntPtr providerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                byte[] pinBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pin);
                SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptAcquireContext(ref providerHandle, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, SafeNativeMethods.CryptContextFlags.Silent)));
                SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptSetProvParam(providerHandle, SafeNativeMethods.CryptParameter.KeyExchangePin, pinBuffer, 0U)));
                SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(certificate.Handle, SafeNativeMethods.CertificateProperty.CryptoProviderHandle, 0U, providerHandle)));
                flag = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473835/rsacryptoserviceprovider-in-net-6

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace X509CertExtension
{
   internal static class X509Certificate2Extension
   {
     public static bool SetPinForPrivateKey(this X509Certificate2 certificate, string pin)
     {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            // Convert RSACng to RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider key = ConvertRSACngToRSACryptoServiceProvider(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey());

            IntPtr providerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            byte[] pinBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pin);
            SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptAcquireContext(ref providerHandle, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, SafeNativeMethods.CryptContextFlags.Silent)));
            SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CryptSetProvParam(providerHandle, SafeNativeMethods.CryptParameter.KeyExchangePin, pinBuffer, 0U)));
            SafeNativeMethods.Execute((Func<bool>)(() => SafeNativeMethods.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(certificate.Handle, SafeNativeMethods.CertificateProperty.CryptoProviderHandle, 0U, providerHandle)));
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

To convert RSACng to RSACryptoServiceProvider in .NET 6, you can use the following code:

```
 public static RSACryptoServiceProvider ConvertRSACngToRSACryptoServiceProvider(RSACng rsaCng)
 {
    RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsaCng.ExportParameters(true);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    return rsaCryptoServiceProvider;
 }
```

Comment: RSACng doesn't contain ProviderName & KeyContainerName here (.NET 6)

Comment: I apologize that I overlooked that .net 6 does not have these features. Can you try using it this way?   `public static RSACryptoServiceProvider ConvertRSACngToRSACryptoServiceProvider(RSACng rsaCng)
 {
     RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsaCng.ExportParameters(true);

     RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
     rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

     return rsaCryptoServiceProvider;
 }`

Comment: Cannot export including private parameters from smart card  
 RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsaCng.ExportParameters(true);