net48 RSACryptoServiceProvider convert public/private keys to net6 rsa importable in linux
I have lots of dotnet48 keys generated via:
  cspParams.KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Exchange;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(KeySize, cspParams))
        {
            // Export public key
            publicKey = rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false);

this byte[] publickey is stored and was opened via
                rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(privateKey);

I need to use the new RSA class in dotnet6 ON LINUX becuase RSACryptoServiceProvider does not work on linux.
How can i import / modify for import this publicKey /privatekey such that I can import it via
            rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey, out int read);

in linux.

Core was developed so same code will run under Windows, Linux, and Mac without changes.  See answer 1 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473835/rsacryptoserviceprovider-in-net-6

Right but this post does not share a way of migrating a precore key to a core key

The key formats differ: rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false) exports the public key as PUBLICKEYBLOB. ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() imports the public key as DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. Therefore, you must extract the public exponent and modulus from the source format and convert it to the target format. A more convenient way for the import may be ImportParameters(), which imports the exponent and modulus directly via RSAParameters (if supported in your environment).

Read the response "Since .NET 4.7 (and all versions of .NET Core) you must not access PrivateKey property on X509Certificate2 object."  Then it says "Instead, you have to use an appropriate X509Certificate2 extension method"
